# Admissibility of representations induced from Hecke algebra for covering groups

Tags: rt.representation-theory, hecke-algebras, covering, admissible-representation

Assume $G$ is a semisimple algebraic group and $B$ is an Iwahori subgroup. Let $(r,E)$ be a representation of $H(G,B)$ which is an Iwahori-Hecke algebra, then Borel proved that $C_{c}(G/B)\otimes_{H}E$ is an admissible G-module in [Admissible representations of a semi-simple group over a local field with vectors fixed under an Iwahori subgroup](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01390139).

Let $\widetilde{G}$ be a $n$-th covering group of $G$ and $\epsilon$ be a faithful character of $\mu_{n}$ in $\widetilde{G}$, my question is whether the genuine $\widetilde{G}$-module $C_{\epsilon}(\widetilde{G}/B)\otimes_{H}E$ is also admissible.

Comment: $B$ is not a subgroup of $\tilde G$, so what ist $\tilde G/B$?

Comment: The maximal compact subgroup $K$ of $G$ is split in $\widetilde{G}$ when (n, char(F)) = 1. So $B$ is also split in $\widetilde{G}$.@Echo

Comment: At which point would Borel's proof fail to transfer to the given case?